# Is $\langle a,b,c \mid c=aba^{-1}b \rangle$ the same as the free group $\langle a,b \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I have a group with generators $a,b$ and $c$ with a relation $c=aba^{-1}b$:
$$\langle a,b,c \mid c=aba^{-1}b \rangle$$
Is this group the same as the free group $\langle a,b \rangle$? (Since $c$ is written in terms of $a$ and $b$.) I’m a bit rusty with the algebra, so I just want to make sure. Thank you.

Comment: can you give isomorphisms between both? I suggest you try it and see if anything goes wrong

Comment: No they are not the same group. But they are isomorphic. (If I set this question on an exam, then the correct answer would be no.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two presentations define isomorphic groups. This is simply an application of a [Tietze transformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations).

Comment: More specifically [Adding a generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations#Adding_a_generator).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is the free group. $c$ is redundant (in words, your presentation says: In the group generated by $a$ and $b,$ there is a word $aba^{-1}b$).

Comment: But $c=aba^{-1}b$ is not a commutator.

Comment: @Shaun yes, reading too quickly. Not that it matters in this case.